# Link gotomeeting with my website

Tags: html, web-applications

could anybody please suggest how can I link gotomeeting code with my website. Meaning can I start meeting putting meeting code in my website and start the meeting.

thanks in advance!

Comment: might want to contact gotomeeting support for that just in case you aren't breaking any user agreement.

Answer (score 1):

Citrix has an API which they just recently released for non-commercial users. You can find the documentation here: https://developer.citrixonline.com/apis